# Inno Setup - installing inf and cat files

Tags: installation, driver, inno-setup, setuptools, inf

I am absolute beginner at creating installer so I found inno setup and created a installer with setup wizard. I can install my program successfully but I have to install my "inf" and "cat" and have no idea how to do it.

[inf and cat file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZv41.png)

I checked similar questions but they have thoughts and errors so they have a idea how to do it. I need a tutorial or guidance for it.

My code below there;

```
#define MyAppName "-"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "-"
#define MyAppURL "-"
#define MyAppExeName "-"

[Setup]
AppId={{72843ACF-C301-4CEE-9B8F-5BFFEC70280F}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\anilo\Desktop\licence.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\anilo\Desktop\Setup Deneme
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "turkish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Turkish.isl"


[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\anilo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\iDeaLAB_v1\iDeaLAB_v1\bin\Debug\app.publish\iDeaLab.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\anilo\Desktop\NT,2000,XP,VISTA,7,8\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs


[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "RUNDLL32.EXE"; Parameters: "SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 C:\Users\anilo\Desktop\NT,2000,XP,VISTA,7,8\cdc_NTXPVista78.inf"
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What does the .cat contain?

Comment: Are you able to install inf by right clicking it and choosing Install option?

Comment: @CKT Yes i can install inf by right clicking. I tried to create batch file that installs inf with pnputil and called it in setup but everytime it says "pnputil is not recognized as an internal or external command". I can run it manually without problem but can't call from any program.

Batch file:
`code
@echo off
cd "%~dp0"
pnputil.exe -i -a "cdc_NTXPVista78.inf"
set /p input= ""
IF "%input%"=="y" echo ok. `